# Which weapons would humans with electric organs invent?

Tags: science-based, biology, earth-like, electricity, electromagnetism

In a **like-earth** scenario, human-like-race discovers to have an *electric organ* in the body.

Imagine it happening with the **progression of 1800**, when most of discoveries took place, leading to a better understanding of our world.

**Which kind of conductive weapons would be the most effective to use? And, how effective would be attacking without one?**

(considering that only humid areas would be easier to handle)

Comment: Your question is far too broad.... The impact over all different aspects of life is impossibly broad. Not to mentioned we don't know where this organ is located. Please limit your question to a very specific situation/aspect. Identify where the organs is located. A choose a technology level or time period.

Comment: @Shadowzee you are right, on it

Comment: We would not have missed something like an electric organs they are large and obvious. they are basically just modified muscle after all.

Comment: perhaps you are looking for an organ that acts like a capacitor, storing energy and being able to release it all at once

Comment: @John I am not referring to our world. These humans are physiologically different, and their not knowing they had this organ, was given by the fact their knowledge of the world was extremely primitive.

Just like scientists discovered facts that nowadays are logical for us, something that needs to be awake (like this specific organ) can go unnoticed.

Comment: @V.Sim yes exactly. And I am exploring what they could use it for. Discharges using a mean (and not only touch, or through water) can be a lot easier in my eyes

Comment: @Shadowzee thank you for your interest. I edited the question if you want to take a look

Comment: Evolution is not going to produce and maintain a useless organs, especially not one as expensive as an electric organ.  electric organs is a single purpose organ if it is not being used it is not going to exist. A species discovering it has an electric organ is like a species discovering it has fully functional legs they never used before, if they have it they already know about it.

Comment: @John definitely right, but mine is just an hypothetical question :) Don't mind too much about how they have it and why it is asleep (they could have forgot how to use it, for example. Maybe after something wiped all memories from the whole human race centuries before)

Comment: I've re-read the problem but I dont think your edit addresses the core problem. We are not here to generate a list of ideas for you to use. We are here to solve specific world building problems. As an example, you could ask "If humans had an electric organ on their hands, how would this affect martial arts". Would less broad because I have identified the organs location and the specific activity it applies to. Please review the policies about asking questions https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @Shadowzee I hope your patience payed off. Reformulated the question

Comment: They would defend themselves with the power of music of music of course

Comment: Doesn't our whole nervous system already work with electricity? Not much of a discovery that..

Answer (score 4):

The Electric Organ will need to work via touch, so I am assuming the organ is actually located on the palm (as this seems to most logical place to use/apply it).

**Why Touch**

When you generate the electricity, it will take the path of least resistance. If it is powerful enough to arc through the air, then your body would have a higher resistance in air and any human opponent would be essentially immune to the electricity. This means you have to apply the electricity via touch which means any fighting styles will need to revolve around hitting the enemy before they can hit you.

The ability would have very limited range, most likely within a couple centimeters (and under humid conditions), however this would essentially limit you to melee range. Any larger and you risk having the electricity you generate arc back onto you and hitting yourself

**Why can't it Arc**

The Electric organ doesn't operate like static electricity. When you become statically charged, you can feel it. Your entire body holds that charge. Your hair goes frizzy and rises up and when you discharge, you feel the shock at the point of discharge. With the electric organ, this is localized, so just your hand becomes charged. The rest of your body is insulated from this charge (because it will stun and kill you). If the Arc can jump a large distance, It can jump back onto you.

**Weapons**

Unfortunately for you, around 1800's guns were become popular and this means hand to hand combat becomes much less popular. If you back up a bit earlier, when guns weren't being used at all, you get a lot more advantages from close quarter combat.

The main weapon of choice would be a

Spears: A metal spear would be a great tool. Not only will it conduct electricity for you, it will greatly extend the range you can use to shock people. Just poke or touch them with the spear and shock away. Once they have been shocked, they will likely break their posture or stance which should give you a clear opening to stab and kill them.

Metal Chains/nets: Metal chains are also a great conductor. Throw them on the enemy and just start zapping away. As your hands have a higher resistance to electricity than you body, you should be safe holding a metal net/chain, however your opponent will have parts draped over their body which will not have the same resistance.

**Armor**

Metal armor would be detrimental against people who can electrocute you. There would be a large shift into leather armor with metal wiring to redirect the electricity into the ground. So instead of knights in shining armor, your just going to get rich knights in fancy looking leather armor.

Comment: Thank you. I really like your answer, especially the idea of spears and how you explained the Arc. Although, I was thinking, you think you could possibly charge an arrow?